# Getting onClick eventargs for the parent of e.target & Adding custom data to propagating onClick args

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Consider two divs. One is the parent. One is the child. The child partially overlaps the parent.

If any area above the parent (even if it's blocked by the child) is clicked, I want to receive the offsetX **for the parent**.

However, since it doesn't appear to be possible as the onClick evenargs are always calculated for the most nested element, I decided to use the following workaround:

1. The child listens for onClicks. Once an onClick comes, it attaches some custom data to the eventargs.

```
const addOnClickInfo = (e) => {
    Object.assign(e, {customInfo: {startOfTimelineElementClicked: start}});
}

return <div onClick={addOnClickInfo} id='te' style={gridMemberStyle}></div>
```

2. The parent listens for onClicks in **capture mode** (**after** the child's function is called) and uses the additional data attached by the child to calculate where the click was relative to the parent.

```
    const onClickHandler = e => {
        console.log(e.customInfo); // IMPORTANT LINE
        console.log(e.customInfo.startOfTimelineElementClicked); // IMPORTANT LINE

    // Here, with startOfTimelineElementClicked we've got enough data to calculate offsetX for the parent.

    };
```

First, is there some other, neater solution (getting eventargs for an element higher in DOM hierarchy than its child that is the actual event.target) to this problem?

Second: the data printed by `console.log`s above is delayed by one click. As the site loads, `e.customInfo` for the first click is `undefined`. From the second click and on it does contain a value, however it's always the one for the previous click. How does it happen?

UPDATE: While the above is true, if we substitute `console.log(e)` for `console.log(customInfo)`, and inspect `e` in Google DevTools, it does seem to contain `customInfo`. Yet, a `console.log(e.customInfo)` literally a line later is `undefined`. Such as:

```
console.log(e) // Expanding it in Google DevTools; clearly has customInfo
console.log(e.customInfo) // undefined...?
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same effect by appending a `ref` to your parent and pass down a function to retrieve the current `offsetX` from the parent

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const ref = useRef(null)

    const getOffset = ref.current ? ref.current.offsetX : null        

    return(
        <div ref={ref}>
            <Child getOffset={getOffset} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And inside your `Child`

```
   const Child = ({ getOffset }) =>{
       const [offset, setOffset] = useState(getOffset())
       return (
           <>
               {`Current parent's offset: ${offset}`}
               <button onClick={() => setOffset(getOffset())}>Refresh offset </button>
           </>
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, captured events are called before non-captured events, not the other way around. This solves this issue.

It probably explains the DevTools issue as well. It loads object data only once you expand the object to view its contents, and by the time I manage to expand it, the event has already finished its bubbling phase.